# Is there a DNS-based policy like SPF or DMARC to require STARTTLS sessions for a given domain?

Tags: dns, email, postfix, ssl, smtp

Ignoring the fact that not all mail servers support TLS:

Is there a way to announce to the world that we would prefer that our inbound mail be delivered via TLS *and* verified as signed by a trusted CA?

Relatedly, can we announce to the world that they should only accept outbound mail *from* us (ie, MAIL FROM) if the connection is TLS?  (I realize they can't know if we verified their cert, but they can know if it was via TLS.)

Either SPF or DMARC seems like a good place to indicate that, but I've not seen support for such a thing.

Comment: MTA-STS - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8461

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, thanks, interesting.  The draft is 4 years old. Any idea how widely deployed this is?

Comment: [Extended Abstract: A First Large-Scale Analysis on Usage of MTA-STS](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-80825-9_18) - paywalled, but the abstract shown gives already some numbers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich can you add that as an answer? It would be +1 from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [MTA-STS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8461) standard for exactly this purpose. It is similar to HSTS in that it declares that the server should be accessed by TLS only. Unlike HSTS it is declared in DNS, so this feature detection can be part of the normal DNS lookups when trying to figure out which server should be used to deliver the mail (i.e. MX lookup).